# mysql query points within polygon - no results

Tags: mysql, polygon, point

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing multiple things wrong here but I'm not sure what...

The table (minus a few fields):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stuff` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lat` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
  `lon` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
  `location` point NOT NULL,  
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `distance` (`distance`),
  KEY `lat` (`lat`),
  KEY `lon` (`lon`),
  SPATIAL KEY `location` (`location`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
```

The triggers to automatically set the location point:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `stuff_insert_defaults`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `stuff_insert_defaults` BEFORE INSERT ON `stuff`
 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.location = PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',NEW.lat,' ',NEW.lon,')'))
//
DELIMITER ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `stuff_update_location`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `stuff_update_location` BEFORE UPDATE ON `stuff`
 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.location = PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',NEW.lat,' ',NEW.lon,')'))
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Some sample data (4 random points within the state of Colorado):

```
/* 4 random points within the state of colorado */
INSERT INTO `stuff` (`id`, `distance`, `lat`, `lon`, `location`) VALUES
(1, 5.0000000, 40.2488450, -103.8003460, 0x000000000101000000f6622827da1f444001df6dde38f359c0),
(2, 5.0000000, 38.4849180, -107.8726700, 0x000000000101000000f19e03cb113e4340d28c45d3d9f75ac0),
(3, 5.0000000, 39.5040250, -105.3584800, 0x000000000101000000e6ae25e483c0434049111956f1565ac0),
(4, 5.0000000, 39.1904180, -106.8179680, 0x000000000101000000ed48f59d5f9843402b4b749659b45ac0);
```

The rough outter boundary of the state of Colorado:

```
NW corner: 41.000497 -109.050149 
NE corner: 41.002380 -102.051881 
SE corner: 36.993237 -102.041959 
SW corner: 36.999037 -109.045220
```

The query which SHOULD return the 4 records we inserted:

```
SELECT *, AsText(location) FROM stuff 
 WHERE Contains(
 GeomFromText('POLYGON((41.000497 -109.050149, 41.002380 -102.051881, 36.993237 -102.041959, 36.999037 -109.045220, 41.000497 -109.050149))'), location );
```

What I'm getting back...

```
nada... 
zip... 
nil... 
nothing...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As documented under [Class `Polygon`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/gis-class-polygon.html) (emphasis added):

> #### *`Polygon`* Assertions
>
> - The boundary of a `Polygon` consists of a set of `LinearRing` objects (that is, `LineString` objects that are both simple ***and closed***) that make up its exterior and interior boundaries.

You must therefore close the polygon by finishing at the starting point:

```
SELECT *, AsText(location) FROM stuff 
 WHERE Contains(
 GeomFromText('POLYGON((41.000497 -109.050149, 41.002380 -102.051881, 36.993237 -102.041959, 36.999037 -109.045220, 41.000497 -109.050149))'), location );
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68148/1/0).

Comment: Nice catch... I'm going back through and testing some others that I have that should produce more results.

Comment: Closing the polygon in the original example worked but when I run the query on the production server I get nothing... even when there are 1000's of possible results.

Comment: this is not accurate, it's like checking against a rectangular, not a polygon

Comment: @tinybyte: You are correct that [`Contains()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html#function_contains) tests against the MBR (as of v5.6.1, one can use [`ST_Contains()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-contains) to test against the exact polygon), but that wasn't the question being asked: I stand by the fact that this post correctly and fully answers the problem posed.